# what is & in typescript and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object

i saw this in the someone else's code.
(this is props of react component.)
i know & is AND logical operater.
i think & has another meaning in this code.
when i use center = {{latitude: number,longitude: number},{zoom: 2, tilt: 2,}}
it is not worked and i know not match vaild format with typescript error.

1. what is & mean in this?
2. how to vaild object format in center props(i use react.)?

```
export interface Coord {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
}
center?: Coord & { zoom?: number; tilt?: number; bearing?: number };
```

Comment: in javascript it is (and always will be) a **BITWISE** AND (not logical) - so, that code make no sense in Javascript - not sure about typoscript

Comment: It's a union of types. It creates a new type that mixes two other types. Read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)

Comment: @fast-reflexes It's an intersection, not a union.

Comment: Now that is very true! Used the wrong word!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` is Intersection Type

Basically, it lets you combine types

like the final object `center` should contain all those keys mentioned in

```
 { zoom?: number; tilt?: number; bearing?: number, latitude, longitude };
```

official doc : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types

The reason that this

```
center = {{latitude: number,longitude: number},{zoom: 2, tilt: 2,}}
```

didn't work is that , first its not a valid object , second  all the keys mentioned ( { zoom?: number; tilt?: number; bearing?: number, latitude, longitude } ) should be present in the object

Comment: Please consider linking to the official documentation for [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) <--